# Ladder loigic software for ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation

I just started a class on industrial motor controls. I am thinking it would be handy to have a [ladder logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_logic) diagram software to help me draw, program, and become familiar with PLCs and ladder logic diagrams. Does anyone know a decent program to do that?

I tooled around in the repos for a bit, but found nothing on ladder logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**PLC-EMU**](http://plcemu.sourceforge.net/)

> [...] a tool for emulating PLCs on a Linux box, using I/O cards. This
>   way you can build a cheap alternative to PLC's, for use with
>   automation applications. It consists of a text-based Ladder Diagram
>   parser, a minimal C API and an optional ncurses-based interface for
>   online control.

[**ClassicLadder**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/classicladder/)

> Free ladder & sequential (grafcet) languages as used on many PLC for
>   programming automation process. Ladder language allows to realize
>   programs on PLC in an electric way. Modbus protocol for SCADA cnx and
>   remote I/O modules. RTLinux/RTAI/Xenomai support for real-time. Can be
>   embedded without GTK interface.

Check also the [PLC index at SourceForge](http://plc.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [The OpenPLC Project](https://www.openplcproject.com/) it's a great choice! Runs on both linux and Windows and has good support.